# Calling php function from jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a `saveTestObject()` method in a `PHP` file, and I need to call it from `HTML` with `jQuery`. I looked around but there seems to be no complete example out there. I would really appreciate one.

Here's my `PHP` file, which is called `SM.php`:

```
<?php

switch($_POST["functionname"]){ 

     case 'saveTestObject': 
        saveTestObject();
        break;   
}   

function saveTestObject() {
    echo "saveTestObject CALLED";

    $object = ParseObject::create("TestObject");
    $objectId = $object->getObjectId();
    $php = $object->get("elephant");

    // Set values:
    $object->set("elephant", "phpserver");
    //$object->set("today", new DateTime());
    $object->setArray("mylist", [1, 2, 3]);
    $object->setAssociativeArray(
      "languageTypes", array("php" => "awesome", "ruby" => "wtf")
    );

    $object->save();
}

?>
```

My `HTML` form in `smpage.html` looks like this:

```
<form>    
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>    
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

How do I connect the two, so that when I press the submit button the `saveTestObject()` function is called?

Both `SM.php` and `smpage.html` reside in the save directory in my web server's `Documents`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got jQuery tagged, so lets use [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) because you're switching on `$_POST["functionname"]`.

```
$("form").submit( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'sw.php',
      data: {"functionname": "saveTestObject"},
      success: function(response) { $("#response").html(response); }
    });
});
```

This will send a request to sw.php, with post data of `functioname = saveTestObject`, thus calling the function because of the `switch` case.

#### Edit

This would make your HTML file become something like;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>    
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>    
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<script>
    $("form").submit( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'sw.php',
          data: {
                "functionname": "saveTestObject", 
                "fname" : $("form input[name=fname]").val(),
                "lname" : $("form input[name=lname]").val()
          },
          success: function(response) { $("#response").html(response); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can then use;

- `$_POST['functionname']`
- `$_POST['fname']`
- `$_POST['lname']`

The `success` is optional, but I like to see the result of the AJAX request. If you do, add a div with the id `response` to your file (`<div id="reponse"></div>`) somewhere you'd like to display the result.

Comment: OK but how do I call this ajax from my html form?

Comment: Have a trigger. Anything. What do you want your trigger to be?

Comment: I imagine that the form inputs are not just for fun - though the OP will need to confirm

Comment: Simply listen for the button click. `$("form").submit( function() {`

Comment: @ʰᵈˑthanks, but could you add a complete example of the html file? I'm new to PHP / jQuery.

Comment: Modified post for you Eddy. @Steve that's been dealt with the edit, thanks!

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ, I have a  echo "saveTestObject CALLED"; inside my saveTestObject function but I'm not seeing it called. Any idea?

Comment: @Eddy - You have the div? Open up the console and see if there are any errors (there shouldn't be)

Comment: How do yon mean the div? I have the console open but there aren't any errors. Shouldn't the echo print to it? Also the saveTestObject function isn't doing the work it's supposed to do.

Comment: Do you have `<div id="reponse"></div>` in your file?

Comment: I added it. It's showing right when the page renders, even before the button click.

Comment: I put a console.log inside the jQuery's success block, and it's being called. But it's also being called if I change the functionname": "saveTasdfestObject" into any other string.

Comment: It shouldn't (http://jsfiddle.net/hhvac235/1/) - Do you have the `$("form").submit( function(event) {` ?

Comment: When I print the response, like this: console.log("success called " + response) from the jQuery success block, the entire php document is printed to the log. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The entire php document being the one with the form, or the one with the `saveTestObject`?

Comment: @hd, Your code doesn't call the function for some reason. It recognizes the SM.php file (if I change the name I get an error.) But the function isn't called, and if I change the name of it to something random, functionname: 'whateverrandom' I don't even get an error message. Is it something with my SM.php? Could you take a look at in in my question?

Comment: Would you be able to look in the console and see the request? Also in `sm.php` can you add `echo print_r($_POST, true);` and see if it's actually posting the functionname value?

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to do an AJAX call to the page.

```
 $('form input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('SM.php', {fname : $('form input[name=fname]').val(), lname : $('form input[name=lname]').val(), functionname: 'saveTestObject'});
 });
```

Just a quick note. preventDefault is needed on this case because it will stop the submission event (which redirects the browser).

**Edit**: Added the url.

Comment: +1 for remembering (and reminding me) on `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @MinusFour, your code doesn't call the function for some reason. It recognizes the SM.php file (if I change the name I get an error.) But the function isn't called, and if I change the name of it to something random, functionname: 'whateverrandom' I don't even get an error message. Is it something with my SM.php? Could you take a look at in in my question?

Comment: Check on your browser network tab (F12 if you are in chrome) and see the ajax call. Check if there's data printed out to SM.php call.

Answer (score 0):

To call that function with ajax you could do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "SM.php", //The requested url
   type:"POST", //The request type, post, get...
   data: {functionname:"saveTestObject"} //The data you want to send to server
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

  //If you submit the form:
  $("form").submit(function(){

    //post data to your php file
    $.post("SM.php", {functionname: 'saveTestObject'}, function(re){
      alert("Saved. returned" + re);
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: I imagine that the form inputs are not just for fun - though the OP will need to confirm

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi Copy this code and past to 'smpage.html' file run it. 
            <script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            $("#formid").submit(function(event){
            $fname_val=$("input[name=fname]").val();
            $lname_val=$("input[name=lname]").val();
               $.ajax({
                    url: "SM.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {'functionname':'saveTestObject','firstname':$fname_val,'lastname':$lname_val},
                    success : function(data){
                          alert("Data saved successfully !");
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('failed');
                    }
                });

            });
            </script>
            <form id="formid">    
                First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
                Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>    
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
            ----------smpage.html---------------------------
```

Comment: None of the alerts shows up, and the echo in the saveTestObject isn't called.

Comment: Hey please add ready function for script i missed this.  $(document).ready(function(){   });

Comment: where should I add it?